# How can I remove icons mistakenly placed on the desktop?

Tags: partitioning, icons

Everything went great with the Ubuntu installation and setup. The 1000 mb hard drive is divided in half with ubuntu on one half and windows XP on the other half. I now regret not making the XP side smaller during the install. I saw that there was a download available called gparted that could enable me to change the size of the partitions. When I downloaded it I wasn't sure what to do with it so I extracted to my desktop. Now there are five icons living on the desktop and don't know what to do to turn them into a useful program or how to get rid of them. Any help, advice or ideas out there would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install application (like gparted for example) is: `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Your desktop files should be on `/home/[username]/Desktop/` you can just delete the files you don't want

Answer (score 0):

Don't download programs. Use apt-get to install applications like so:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Also, you can't change the size of an existing partition while it is in use so you must run gparted from a live CD like the one you used to install ubuntu to make the changes to these partitions.

You will not need to install gparted in the live session as it should already be installed.

As for your desktop icons, I would need more information or a screenshot to diagnose the problem.